# Can a form be used inside a figure element

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Quick question: Can a `<form>` be used inside a `<figure>` element? I'm thinking a contact form, for example, would be

> "self-contained,[... is] as a single unit from the main flow of the
>   document, and [...] can be moved away from the main flow of the
>   document without affecting the document’s meaning."-[[<figure>
>   spec]](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html)

code snippet:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Contact Us</figcaption>
    <form>
        <input name="email"...
        <textarea name="comments"...
        <input type="submit"...
    </form>
</figure>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I question the semantics despite the good answers given. Is a form a figure?

Comment: Yeah, I'm torn about that. _Is_ a form a figure? I mean `<figure>` is distinct from `<aside>` and, like @Steve pointed out, `<form>` is in fact a flow element.

Comment: Many HTML element names are more or less misleading, and HTML5 adds to the confusion. The question seems to be about “semantics” and to be based on the element *name* `figure` rather than the proposed *definition* of the element in HTML5 drafts. But interpreted as a syntactic question, it is constructive and has been answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are technically allowed to do that. If it is semantically correct in your case, that is another question (and I would probably disagree with it).

Why it is technically allowed:

In the link to the [HTML5 figure spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html) you posted yourself, you will see:

> Permitted contents: One figcaption element, followed by flow content

And since a `<form>` element is considered a [`flow element`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow), you are good.

Comment: Good question. :)  It is mostly a gut feeling. Any reference to `figure` I have seen so far always considers the content as some visual addition to the main content (hence it offers a `figcaption`).  Your example seems to suggest to me the use of an `aside` with a `hX` element inside.  But then again, I don't think you are completely wrong either way.

Comment: For now, I'm scrapping that direction then. My gut says no. I kinda felt that way also, that figure should be a "visual addition to the main content"... the form is a functional element (the PRIME function of a contact page, particularly) and not simply a visual addition. Thanks for being a backboard!

Answer (score 1):

From the HTML 5 Nightly:

*"The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning."*

Given the last part, I think your better off wrapping the form in a `<div>` or just wrapping the inner contents of the form in a `<fieldset>` element. I think that `<figure>` is more appropriate for images, videos, audio, code snippets, etc. but thats just my opinion.

[Take a look at section 4.5 of the HTML 5 spec for more insight](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)

Comment: I'd considered using `<fieldset>` for my purposes, but that wouldn't be appropriate as it is supposed to group "a set of form controls". Thanks for the quick response.